# How To Add IDENTITY Function For The App Installation

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, identity, unityscript

Want to know the code to add IDENTITY access function which is asked before installating any ANDROID APP.

I am making a game in UNITY 3D. I want the code and how to add that code/script to my game/engine to get the IDENITY access when someone installs app.

Awaiting response anxiously.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to add permissions to your app, you should check your [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).